# problem NestedKeyof type with circularly references objects

Tags: typescript, keyof

So I am buildining a library and trying to implement `NestedKeyof`

And I found this.

```js
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> =  {
  [Key in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[Key] extends object 
? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<T[Key]>}`
: `${Key}`
}[keyof T & (string | number)];
```

Which works just fine.

The problem I am facing now is with `circularly references objects` which I get the following issue

```
Type of property 'self' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ [Key in "self" | "name" | "imageManagerIdentifier" | "x"]: Cirulare[Key] extends object ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<Cirulare[Key]>}` : `${Key}`; }'.(2615)
```

Here is the full test code

```js
class Cirulare {
  name: string;
  self: Cirulare;
  public imageManagerIdentifier = 'ImageHandler';
  x: number;
  constructor() {
    (this.name = 'asd'), 
    (this.self = this);
    this.x = 0;
  }
}


type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> =  {
  [Key in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[Key] extends object 
? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<T[Key]>}`
: `${Key}`
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

const fn<T> = (keys: NestedKeyOf<T>[])=> {

}

fn<Cirulare>(["name",...])
```

Is there a way to disable the warning/error or simple solve it

Comment: You could build a depth limiter like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxaPbW) shows.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That solved it thx, you can add the answer

Comment: Another thing if you could also inc if it only show display none functions

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance. I might drop a link in a comment showing how to exclude function props but that’s outside the scope of the question as asked.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDDxlN) might be what you mean for excluding functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `NestedKeyOf<T>` would necessarily produce an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) on a recursive data structure (e.g., `"self" | "self.self" | "self.self.self" | "self.self.self.self" | ...`), and TypeScript cannot represent such things.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#44792](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44792) to allow [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to be defined in terms of themselves directly, but there is currently no support for this as of TypeScript 4.9.

---

One possible way to avoid this problem is to build a *depth limiter* type parameter into the type definition.  So when you evaluate `NestedKeyof<T, D>` where `D` represents a finite depth, each nested evaluation will result in decrementing `D` by one until you reach zero, at which point you do not evaluate further.  It turns out to be easier to represent this with [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of a given length instead of a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (one can readily use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to shorten tuples by one element, whereas there is no built-in support for subtracting one from a numeric literal type).

For example:

```
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object, D extends any[] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]> =
    D extends [any, ...infer DD] ? ({
        [K in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[K] extends object
        ? `${K}` | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<T[K], DD>}`
        : `${K}`
    }[keyof T & (string | number)]) : never;
```

Here the `D` type argument is checked to see if it has any elements in it; if not, then `NestedKeyOf<T, []>` results in `never`, and there is no recursion.  Otherwise, the `D` type argument has its first element peeled off, leaving `DD`, and the nested calls use `NestedKeyOf<T[K], DD>`.

I've given `D` a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, so if you write `NestedKeyOf<T>` without a `D` you'll get up to eight levels of recursion.  If you need more or less you can adjust it, but keep in mind that if you make it too deep you will hit type instantiation warnings again.

---

Let's try it out on `Circulare`:

```
type Z = NestedKeyOf<Cirulare>
/* type Z = "name" | "self" | "imageManagerIdentifier" | "x" | "self.name" | "self.self" | 
"self.imageManagerIdentifier" | "self.x" | "self.self.name" | "self.self.self" |
"self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" | "self.self.x" | "self.self.self.name" | 
"self.self.self.self" | "self.self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" | "self.self.self.x" |
"self.self.self.self.name" | "self.self.self.self.self" | 
"self.self.self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" | 
"self.self.self.self.x" | "self.self.self.self.self.name" | "self.self.self.self.self.self" | 
"self.self.self.self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" | "self.self.self.self.self.x" | 
"self.self.self.self.self.self.name" | "self.self.self.self.self.self.self" | 
"self.self.self.self.self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" | "self.self.self.self.self.self.x" | 
"self.self.self.self.self.self.self.name" | "self.self.self.self.self.self.self.self" | 
"self.self.self.self.self.self.self.imageManagerIdentifier" |
"self.self.self.self.self.self.self.x" */
```

Looks good.  In the above you can see that the recursion stops after eight levels, so you have `"self.self.self.self.self.self.self.self"` but not anything longer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCWAnAruRBTaBvAsAKGkOgDswBbdALmggBdF5iBzAbnyJvRADNqEU06NgSIAHZACMQ8YNHhkwTdAFkwpJYgCSAE3TFa8bvHSJoAXmgByTQqUAJNdpAnLwjgA9qxZGQkm3RMAA9sR0KMC0QYgAFACU2OwcRNG0ABbwEAB0pBTmVpDalrEANIlJSSnpWRBc3HlpGbEB5Q1Z7nkADM3QAL74fXj4+LQAnqKYAHLodOjaANLoIwDy3AA8ACrQ6O60etowQRIAVugRxdAAIls7ezBqIwDaALp5Dx3n79Cf3x+-X08APnMZUu112xH20Ae93OmThjG4JkuFxeAH5oNFcCJyg85nJiNAANaLIJ1TYAMgxYUYTGgAB8SD4-IhYk9qOtcS9tuDIYcThEQRx0QADAAkWDmPWF9OgYolPUy4qmM3mixWG055wuFwBUsFRGocslwpBPQexJGpOgFKp9BpMu8vhMrPiXnQADd-EM8KNxtAAFp5ZW7VXLNb8VBgDAA-AAegAVNBfZhAxYAEQ5dBpmVpmo8bMMtPyRQqNQlrS6fSGYyIAvQNPuOu52rZchZnN57iZTt1-DNniZYtKVTqEw6PQGIwmJudzKNjst2eZmeL1f5+nsftd2dD0ujisT6vThcD2fzwuzy8t5cyzdX09r7grh8vru7kfl8dVqe1k-bx9zgWiRbt2AFLm2z7-q+oGvpBMFQQhg62Hun6VpONa9iIIH3oh571jh8GEeBFBwQRZG1JhhDYWBAHvmWGhfuhx4XjR0FnpR+GsYhBE3ixbFcURFG3lh5H8dBdH7oxR6-nx3ECex0CJLJgliXJA68ZxqkqWpCFpmUymiTphESahh4-qR8kCfO8axt6wShLQ0DcASFgbGCtzQHypy0AC0QWhA1DBrMCxhhsALPPEZhAlgvTes5qwRoIvkPBmEFPLEQA)